# Fluent Nhibernate inner join

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mapping, inner-join, fluent

I have 3 tables (Master, Imagen, Linea) were:

```
Master
public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
public virtual Imagen imagen { get; set; }

Imagen
public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
public virtual Linea linea { get; set; }

Linea
public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
public virtual String Nombre { get; set; }
```

I need a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Master 
INNER JOIN dbo.Imagen ON dbo.Master.imagen_id = dbo.Imagen.Id 
INNER JOIN dbo.Linea ON dbo.Imagen.linea_id = dbo.Linea.Id 
WHERE dbo.Linea_Id = 5
```

But I dont know how to tell Fluent Nhibernate to create this query using the automapper.
So far I've tried this:

```
ICriteria c = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Master))
  .CreateAlias("dbo.Imagen", "img", JoinType.InnerJoin)
  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("img.linea_id", id_linea));

return c.List<Master>();
```

But I get this error: 
could not resolve property: dbo of: ImageManager.Model.Entity.Master

Any ideas on how to do a Inner Join? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a start I would get rid of the dbo from dbo.Imagen.  Using the ICriteria interface you need to think in-terms of objects, not database tables, even though there may be a one to one mapping of object to table and properties to columns.

**EDIT:**
another option would be to use the QueryOver Lambda syntax.

```
   var list = session.QueryOver<Master>()
                        .JoinQueryOver(master => master.imagen)
                        .Where(imagen => imagen.linea.Id == 5)
                        .List();
```

Comment: Thanks, Alredy did that. Im really new to Fluent Nhibernate.

Comment: I tried this but I get this error: "could not resolve property: imagen.linea.Id of: ImageManager.Model.Entity.Master"
I also changed to .Where(Master => Master.imagen.linea.Id == 5) but i get the same error

Comment: Sorry about that... still learning the QueryOver syntax myself. Will fix.

Comment: it works!!!, thanks a lot. Anyway I end up using ICriteria because I needed to get the images and lines related to that master, thats why I added createalias for imagen and hdd, if I didnt do that i get a LazyLoadException when I try to access to image or hdd properties on my master object.

Comment: here is the code:
    ICriteria c = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(MasterHdd))
    .CreateAlias("imagen", "img", JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .CreateAlias("hdd", "h", JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .CreateAlias("img.linea", "lin", JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("lin.Id", id_linea));
    return c.List<MasterHdd>();

Answer (score 3):

I can't  work out from your previous comments if you have already fixed it but I would try

```
ICriteria c = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Master))

.CreateAlias("imagen", "img", JoinType.InnerJoin)
.CreateAlias("img.linea", "lin", JoinType.InnerJoin)
.Add(Restrictions.Eq("lin.Id", 5));

return c.List<Master>();
```

EDIT : Casing changed as stated below.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm currently working on this. The problem is that is not working. This is the error I get: "could not resolve property: Imagen of: ImageManager.Model.Entity.Master"

Im using Automapping to Map everythin under model folder:
.Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(model)))

in the model folder I have a sub folder called Entity and  there i have the entities:

Comment: public class Master{
public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
public virtual Imagen imagen { get; set; }
public virtual Hdd hdd { get; set; }
public virtual String hash_master { get; set; }
}

Comment: public class Linea{
public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
public virtual int ObjVersion { get; set; }
public virtual String Nombre { get; set; }
public virtual String Tabla { get; set; }
public virtual String NombreCorto { get; set; }
}

public class Imagen{
public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
public virtual String PartNumber { get; set; }
public virtual String Version { get; set; }
public virtual String So { get; set; }
public virtual String Revision { get; set; }
public virtual Linea linea { get; set; }
public virtual String Nombre { get; set; }
}

Comment: I think the only problem with this answer will be the case of the object references.  you have Imagen where @lloiacono has his object reference is all lowercase - imagen. Linea reference will be the same. That may be the reason why it's not working.

Comment: Good spot. Casing changed in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @NathanFisher that was indeed the problem. I dont get the error anymore, could you recommend me a good manual for fluent, I read the wiki but I cannot find anythin about Icriteria.

Comment: Have a look at the summer of nhibernate series by stephen bohlen, its a few years old now but the basics are there for ICriteria and nhibernate in general. also have a look at http://funnelweblog.com  it's an open-source blog platform based on fluent-nhibernate