# nHibernate complex Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate

I have a problem querying using nHibernate.
I have the following entities:

```
public class CostAmount  
{  
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}  
    public virtual Year Year{get; set;}  
    public virtual Month Month{get; set;}  
}  

public class Year  
{  
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}  
    public virtual string Code {get;set;}  
}  

public class Month  
{  
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}  
    public virtual string Code {get;set;}  
}
```

I want to query using some sql like the following:

```
select * from CostAmount ca  
inner join Year y on ca.YearID = y.ID  
inner join Month m on ca.MonthID = m.ID  
where y.Code *100+m.Code between 9107 and 9207
```

Can any one help me please.

Comment: Sadly for you, the QueryOver syntax doesn't have support for math operations. You'll have to do horrible things like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828552/are-there-any-arithmetic-operation-projections-in-nhibernate

Comment: And I hope your Code(s) are `int`, otherwise I don't know how you could multiply it.

Comment: What did you try? HQL? Criteria? Linq?

Answer (score 2):

As I've written, NHibernate QueryOver has poor syntax for math operations... Now, if we consider `Code` to be an `int` (because I normally don't multiply strings by 100):

```
// Aliases
CostAmount costAmount = null;
Year year = null;
Month month = null;

// Projections for the math operations

// y.Code * 100
var proj1 = Projections.SqlFunction(
    new VarArgsSQLFunction("(", "*", ")"),
    NHibernateUtil.Int32,
    Projections.Property(() => year.Code),
    Projections.Constant(100)
);

// proj1 + m.Code 
var proj2 = Projections.SqlFunction(
    new VarArgsSQLFunction("(", "+", ")"),
    NHibernateUtil.Int32,
    proj1,
    Projections.Property(() => month.Code)
);

// The query

var query = Session.QueryOver(() => costAmount)
                   .JoinAlias(() => costAmount.Year, () => year)
                   .JoinAlias(() => costAmount.Month, () => month)
                   .Where(Restrictions.Between(proj2, 9107, 9207));

var res = query.List();
```

The trick for math operations was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10756598/613130

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check this question [Fluent Nhibernate inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916663/fluent-nhibernate-inner-join)

Or maybe from this explanation can guide you to find the right answer.
http://ayende.com/blog/4023/nhibernate-queries-examples